# Can onchange be triggered within HTML for DIV by passing function(this.value);

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dom

Here is some simple code where, when div tag text is changed, an alert should fire:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Modify the text by clicking on it, then click outside the field to fire the onchange event.</p>


<div type="text" name="txt" value="" onchange="myFunction(this.value)" contenteditable="true">Change Value by clicking here</div>

<script>
function myFunction(val) {
  alert("The input value has changed. The new value is: " + val);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Can this be done without using event listeners?

Comment: Try like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/k98z4wdh/)

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't want to use an event listener, you can use the `onInput` attribute, like this:

```js
function myFunction(el) {
  alert("The input value has changed. The new value is: " + el.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <p>Modify the text by clicking on it, then click outside the field to fire the onchange event.</p>


  <div type="text" name="txt" value="" oninput="myFunction(this)" contenteditable="true">Change Value by clicking here</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @DracoMalfoy Great! Please mark the answer as correct, then, so others know the question is resolved. :)